# POST request works in Postman but is blocked from React front end. No CORS error, not making it to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, cors, postman

I have a database setup on Dokku that is currently functioning fine with Postman. My full stack React front end and Rails back end are functioning locally, but when I attempt the same fetch calls (only difference in code is the url), the requests don't have any parameters and are blocked before ever reaching the server.

Here's an example of a fetch call I'm trying (using Redux):

```
export const createPurchase = purchase => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(baseURL + 'purchases', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accepts": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ amount: purchase.amount, bundle_name: purchase.bundleName, user_id: purchase.userId })
   })
     .then(resp => resp.json())
     .then(userObj => {
       console.log('purchase created!')
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
}
```

Reading my Rails server logs on Dokku shows that it isn't aware that requests are being made. My CORS file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why the fetch requests are automatically getting blocked when I am allowing everything with CORS, do I need to add a header to the fetch requests?

Comment: What is your ```baseURL```?

Comment: This is what it is defined as: 

`const baseURL = "http://67.205.164.245:6714/api/v1/" `

Comment: Open the Network pane in browser devtools and examine the requests and responses there. You see and OPTIONS request there? What’s the status code of the response to that OPTIONS request? And exactly what messages in the browser logging in the devtools console?